# 3ds max 2014 - import FBX from Maya 2017 then see nothing

Tags: 3ds-max, maya, import

According to [Transfering a 3ds Max scene to Maya and vice versa](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Transfering-a-3ds-Max-scene-to-Maya-and-vice-versa.html)

> Export the scene file as fbx and import the fbx into the other application.

I use Maya 2017 to export my scene into a FBX file. Then I try to import this FBX file into 3ds max 2014. In 3ds max 2014, I have tried both "Autodesk Media & Entertainment" & "Autodesk Architectural (Revit)" import preset, but after the import process done (I see no error), I see nothing in the scene - like nothing ever get imported.

I have tried to import this same FBX file into Maya 2017, and everything work fine. So I guess this must be 3ds max 2014 fault.

Note: If I use Obj file instead of Fbx file, then 3ds max 2014 can import and see the model, but the animation just not get imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out the problem here is because of the file version of FBX file format.

To make the 3Ds max 2014 read the fbx exported from Maya 2017, we must edit the export settings in Maya 2017 a bit.

In Maya 2017:

File > Export All... (click the setting box)
In "Export All Options" Dialog, click "Edit preset..." > "Edit export preset" dialog pops up."
Set "Advanced Options" > "FBX File Format" > "Version" = "FBX 2014/2015" like in the image below
[image: Maya2017 FBX version for 2014]